# How to get merged data frame from two data frames having some same columns(R)

Tags: r

I want to merge them and find the values of one dataframe that would like to be added to the existing values of the other based on the same columns.

For example:

`df1`

| No | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

`df2`

| No | A | B | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Finally, I want the output table like this.

`df`

| No | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Note: I did try `merge()`, but in this case, it did not work.
Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

**Reproducible sample data**

```
df1 <- 
structure(list(No = 1:3, A = c(1L, 0L, 0L), B = c(0L, 1L, 0L), 
    C = c(1L, 2L, 1L), D = c(0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- 
structure(list(No = 1:3, A = c(1L, 0L, 2L), B = c(0L, 1L, 1L), 
    E = c(1L, 2L, 1L), F = c(1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first row-bind the two dataframes and then compute the sum of each column while 'grouping' by the `No` column. This can be done like so:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
  group_by(No) %>%
  summarise(across(c(A, B, C, D, E, `F`), sum, na.rm = TRUE), 
            .groups = "drop")
```

If a particular column doesn't exist in one dataframe (i.e. columns `E` and `F`), values will be padded with `NA`. Adding the `na.rm = TRUE` argument (to be passed to `sum()`) means that these values will get treated like zeros.

Comment: No problem! In that case, would you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 4):

You can also carry out this operation by `left_join`ing these two data frames:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = "No") %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with(".x"), ~ .x + get(str_replace(cur_column(), "\\.x", "\\.y")))) %>%
  rename_with(~ str_replace(., "\\.x", ""), ends_with(".x")) %>%
  select(!ends_with(".y"))

  No A B C D E F
1  1 2 0 1 0 1 1
2  2 0 2 2 1 2 1
3  3 2 1 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: @AnilGoyal Thank you. It's a bit verbose but I think it is quite effective with more variables.

Comment: Yes, If OP wants it to do in dplyr

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill = TRUE)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), No]

#   No A B C D E F
#1:  1 2 0 1 0 1 1
#2:  2 0 2 2 1 2 1
#3:  3 2 1 1 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R` (with `R 4.1.0`).  Get the values of the objects in a `list` ('lst1').  Then, find the `union` of the column names ('nm1').  Loop over the `list` assign to create 0 value columns with `setdiff` in each `list` element, `rbind` them and use `aggregate` to get the `sum` grouped by 'No'

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern= '^df\\d+$'))
nm1 <- lapply(lst1, names) |>
   {\(x) Reduce(union, x)}()


lapply(lst1, \(x) {x[setdiff(nm1, names(x))] <- 0; x}) |>
     {\(x) do.call(rbind, x)}() |> 
   {\(dat) aggregate(.~ No, data = dat, FUN = sum, na.rm =  TRUE, 
            na.action = na.pass)}()
#  No A B C D E F
#1  1 2 0 1 0 1 1
#2  2 0 2 2 1 2 1
#3  3 2 1 1 0 1 0
```